# Is there a way to get complete output from child_process.spawn method in node

Tags: node.js, angular, child-process, stdio, spawn

I am trying to run `ng lint --format json` command using node's `child_process` spawn method. The code looks like below:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const jsonLog = fs.createWriteStream('test.json', { flags: 'a' });
const linter = spawn('ng', ['lint', '--format', 'json']);
linter.stdout.pipe(jsonLog);
```

As you can guess, I am trying to output JSON to a file. The problem I am facing is that I am not getting the complete JSON output. It gets truncated at some point making it an invalid JSON. I think it has to do something with buffer size.

Now most of you will suggest me this:

```sh
ng lint --format json > jsonFile.json
```

I am already aware of it. I want to do it programmatically because I am trying to build a utility for it. Let me know if you have any ideas or solution.

Comment: did you try to put a `setInterval` in your script? if you get all the output it means that your program ends before receiving all the data, so you should wait for the `end` event on the stdout stream

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Isn't ``data`` event called several times before the ``end`` event is called. How do you suggest I should use ``setInterval`` in this case?

Comment: setInterval doesn't let the process ending, it would be just a fast-check to be sure this is the problem.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I am still not sure what do you mean. If you can redirect me to some example that would be a great help.

Comment: add `setInterval(()=>{}, 1000)` at the bottom of your script. what is the output of the file now?

Comment: PS with standard fs `const fs = require('fs')` works for me